# How do I add an interval update system to my bots status?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

As I'm newish to Discord.js, I'm having some issues with variables and such.

How can I change this code, so it displays the number of users in those guilds as well as updates every 5-10 minutes?

`` client.user.setActivity(`${PREFIX}help | on ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers`); ``

Comment: Hi Cam, you may want to add any error messages you are getting, or what else you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `client.setInterval()`:

```js
client.setInterval(() => {
  client.user.setActivity(`${PREFIX}help | on ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers`);
}, 300000) // Runs every 5 minutes
```